# Buildozer Error-"install mpmath version >=0.19"

Tags: python, android, kivy, sympy, buildozer

Trying to deploy an android app using Buildozer. build with Kivy, based on Sympy package.

**getting the next error lines:**

```
      STDOUT:
Please install the mpmath package with a version >= 0.19


  STDERR:

    # Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain 
create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --
requirements=python3,kivy,sympy --arch armeabi-v7a 
--copy-libs --color=always --
storage-dir="/home/ohad/Scalc/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21
```

.
.
.
.

```
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Imports of my script, not include Kivy's imports:

```
    from sympy import *
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import standard_transformations, \
    implicit_multiplication_application
```

**Update**:
After trying to deploy without sympy, it worked, the app crashed immediately on the phone, so its a problem with mpmath,sympy for sure

Full output of command: `sudo buildozer android debug deploy run`

https://github.com/Ohadforman/Error-buildozer/blob/master/Error

any ideas?

Comment: its answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34214635/sympy-installed-however-sympy-mpmath-not-found

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sympy installed, however sympy.mpmath not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34214635/sympy-installed-however-sympy-mpmath-not-found)

Comment: @GuneshShanbhag It looks for me like another problem, the buildozer "asks" for another version, while in my script I'm not even using mpmath. actually I think the critical problem is in the STDERR step. and I'm not totally sure that the cause of it is sympy or mpmath.

Comment: can u provide whole output of command ```sudo buildozer android debug deploy run```

Comment: @GuneshShanbhag https://github.com/Ohadforman/Error-buildozer/blob/master/Error

Comment: After trying to deploy without sympy it worked, the app crushed immediately on the phone, so its a problem of mpmath,sympy for sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find solution.

1. you should install mpmath on your python interpreter
2. cut or copy mpmath folder
3. find sympy folder on you project project_folder/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/sympy/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/sympy
   some folders should be named different
4. paste mpmath folder into folder from 3 step

I wish it help you, for me it's work

in addition. When i try to make it on new project it doesnt work. In first time you should try build project without sympy on spec file, after it you can add sympy on spec file and add mpmath module on folder in my answer